# Issue using kivy textinput's 'input_type' property

Tags: python, kivy

Hi im having issues with using the input_type property of kivy's textinput widget. The thing is i made two custom text input one i called  StrText where i set input_type = 'text'. Then a second text input named NumText with input_type = 'number'.
I tested this on my phone using kivy launcher, and noticed that once i tap on the NumText input and it brings a number keyboard, if i tap on the StrText, it brings the same number keyboard instead of a normal text keyboard. If you play with it a little you'll notice mostly number key board is returned most of the time.
Please is there something wrong with my code, or how can i fix this?
You'll find my code below

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.core.window import Window

class  BubbleApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.fullscreen = False
    BubbleApp().run()
```

bubble.kv

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    StrText:
        height: '48dp'
        size_hint_y: None

    Label:
        text: 'Number keyboard below'
        height: '48dp'
        size_hint_y: None
        multiline: False
        font_size: self.height * .5

    NumText:
        height: '48dp'
        size_hint_y: None


<StrText@TextInput>:
    input_type: 'text'
    multiline: False
    font_size: self.height * .5

<NumText@TextInput>:
    input_type: 'number'
    input_filter: 'int'
    multiline: False
    font_size: self.height *.5
```

Comment: What type of keyboard do you use? Default android, samsung, some custom?

Comment: It's TouchPal 2015

Comment: Try to change it to the default keyboard if it works.

Comment: Just did. And it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Now you know why it doesn't work - the problem is with the custom keyboard. Had the same issue a long ago :-/

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean that if I made an app and a user has a custom keyboard selected, this problem would occur? It would seem best not to use it at all.

Comment: May and may not. I think the issue is with the coding of the custom keyboard, because if it works with the default one, maybe the coder of the custom kb didn't understand some principle of how to make one the right way.

Comment: Alright. That's good to know

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Also, you can purge user's keyboard and use your own(e.g. kivy built-in kb) on focus or touch in TextInput area, therefore it'll be the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced similar issue when I built my App using Kivy1.10.0. I used the default keyboard app in android but still it was keep changing from **Numeric Keypad** to **Text Keypad**.

This time I tried kivy==1.9.1 with Cython==0.23.1 and buildozer==0.32 to build the .apk and it worked for me.

**Note:**

I suggest to create a virtualenv to install above specific packages and use it to create the .apk file.

```
virtualenv build32env
source build32env/bin/activate
pip install buildozer==0.32 Cython==0.23.1
```

After executing `buildozer init` make sure to change `buildozer.spec` file:

from

```
requirements = kivy
```

to

```
requirements = kivy==1.9.1
```

otherwise it will use the latest kivy version to build the .apk file.

[More details about buildozer](http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Hope it helps others!