# Setting Google keyboard in kivy and kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, textinput, gboard, kivymd

So, I've been using kivymd and it is working just fine, but there is something i've been searching for and i couldn't get the answer, its about google keyboard on android.

When you want to write on kivy textinput or MDTextField, the google keyboard that's popped up isn't showing suggestions and can't do slide typing, do you guys know how to fix this?
[The keyboard that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Vv4.jpg)

[the keyboard i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smnnR.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Use these properties in text fields.

```
input_type: "text"
keyboard_suggestions: True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case the OP still needs an answer, and for others like me who found this, I thought I'd post what I think the answer is here.

Unfortunately this seems to be a bug in Kivy.  Insofar as I can understand the issue, the Kivy TextInput class does not listen to the `on_textedit` event (I may not be understanding this correctly).  A discussion on this issue can be found in [this bug](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/2015) and in this [pull request](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/6716).  In effect, if I've understood correctly, Kivy ends up telling Android that it wants a keyboard for a password field.  Hence glide typing, suggestions etc. are not present and the `keyboard_suggestions` property of the TextInput class makes no difference.

Until this bug is fixed (and unfortunately I have no idea how to help with this), there seem to be two possible workarounds. I have not really tried either, however.

- The first one is referred to in this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989388/issue-using-kivy-textinputs-input-type-property), where someone downgraded Kivy to 1.9.1 (as well as Cython and buildozer) and managed to address the issue referred to in that question (which should be similar to this problem I think).
- The second one is referred to in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/90gjhc/i_need_autocomplete_in_kivy/), where someone suggests subclassing the relevant Android class with `pyjnius`. This class is `android.widget.EditText`, and I'm trying this out, without success so far.

**NB**: My  mistake, this is not a bug in Kivy, but in the underlying SDL library. You can find the discussion [here.](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4775)